# Retrieve a String type column from a Spark Dataset as String variable, to pass that as a 'key' for the Redis cache

Tags: apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming, spark-redis

I am trying to use spark streaming to read the data from a kafka topic.

The message from kafka is a JSON which i am storing below in the value column of the dataset as String.

**Sample message : Just a sample, actual json is complex**

```json
{
    "Name": "Bauddhik",
    "Profession": "Developer"
}
```

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)");
```

Now as my Dataset have a value column with the entire JSON, I need to pick one of the field which i can use as a key while storing in Redis. Suppose the field is "Name" from the json.

So, first i did below select to take out the "name" field as a new column in my dataframe.

```java
Dataset<Row> df1 = df.select(functions.col("value"), functions.get_json_object(functions.col("value"), "$['name']").as("name");
```

This works fine and now my df2 looks like

```
Value         |       name
<Json>        |     Bauddhik
```

Now i want this to be inserted to Redis cache with the key as 'Bauddhik' and the value as the entire Json. So i am using below foreachbatch option to persist in Redis.

```java
df1.writeStream().foreachbatch (
   new VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>() {
      public void call (Dataset<Row> dataset, Long batchId) {
          dataset.write()
              .format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
              .option("key.coloum", **<hereistheissue>**)
              .option("table","test")
              .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
              .save();
    }
}).start()
```

If you look at the above code (**hereistheissue**) , I need to paas the key as Bauddhik which i derived earlier as a seperate column in the Dataframe.

I am not able to retrieve the name column as string so i can pass it to the Redis cache as the key. I have tried using map and `df.head().getString(1)` but nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone please guide on how I can read a column from a dataset as a String and pass to the key option while writing to Redis cache.

Answer (score 0):

you have misspelled column in your code...

```py
.option("key.coloum", **<hereistheissue>**)
```

should be..

```py
.option("key. Column", **<hereistheissue>**)
```